# where File-based Sessions `s file store on system file?

Tags: python, django, session

whene use SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.file" as backend where sessions file created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on django document:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#session-file-path

If you’re using file-based session storage, this sets the directory in which Django will store session data. When the default value (None) is used, Django will use the standard temporary directory for the system

linux:   /tmp

windows: %userprofiles%\AppData\Local\